# Laravel-Project deployment via FTP

Tags: laravel, deployment, ftp, devops

I want to deploy my Laravel-Project but it always shows me this error:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at admin to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

My Server Structure is like that:

```
/
   /protected --> All Files and Folders within the project (+ /node_modules & /vendor) except the /public-folder
   /public_html --> all Files and Folders within the /public-folder
```

I already changed the permissions for the /storage-folder and I already changed the paths in the /index.php to

`require __DIR__.'/../protected/vendor/autoload.php';`

and

`$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../protected/bootstrap/app.php';`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

place all the files from your localhost (htdocs) to public_html. Also make sure there is no any redirection in your domain-redirection on your hosting server.
The main reason of the internal server error is that your domain is not pointing the directory which you define.

In my case, the index.php file is

require **DIR**.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

Do all the changes one by one, this will work in your case hopefully. I have mentioned the reference link below please check

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-deploying-to-server-using-ftp

Comment: Hm I have no htdocs-folder on my server. currently there is nothing more than all the files from the Laravel-project.

The root points to /public_html, so this shouldn't be the problem I think.

Comment: And the problem is as well that I can't make any changes via ssh at the server, so I can't composer install

Comment: do you have shared-hosting or dedicated? because there is another way to deploy laravel project to shared hosting. please check this one and try https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e

Comment: Is that issue fixed? please do all the steps one by one, hope this will be resolved

Comment: Jep I've done that but as I said I can't enter commands via ssh. Nevertheless it is working now. The .htaccess caused a problem at my server

Comment: .htaccess file was must redirecting to any invalid path, anyhow it is good to hear that your problem is resolved.